# Why is my texture appearing differently in texture mode compared to render display mode?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, node-editor, texture-painting

I have a question. I needed to hide seam marks on my model so I used clone stamp. The problem is that it looks good in every display method (texture/material) except in "rendered" display method. Here are some pictures
How to make it visible in render method?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume Blender Render tag is unnecesary in your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess would be that you haven't saved the image after texture painting and/or reloaded it so Cycles isn't seeing the updated texture yet.

If you are in texture paint mode you can choose 'Save All Images' from the 'Slots' tab of the toolbar to save any edited images to disk:

[image]

You can then reload the image node in the node editor by selecting the image node and from the 'Properties' panel (Press <kbd>N</kbd> while in the node editor) and choose the 'Reload' button:

[image]

**Note:** I have sometimes found the need to switch from rendered view to another view and then back to rendered view for the image texture to update.

Comment: One more thing, do I need to save it each time to see some changes, or there is the other way?

Comment: I think you will need to save it each time if it was the saving that was the issue.

Comment: Looks like its a bug, it happens quite often when baking a texture few times too, saving the texture and reloading from the hard drive solving that problem.

Comment: No, it's not a bug...just the way it works, and yes, it will not only happen quite often, but should happen always :)